# In Rethink db ,how can i retrieve key-value pair in below scenario?

Tags: java, rethinkdb

```
{
 "id" :"Reserved"
 "1" :"Free"
 "2" :"Free"
 "3" :"Reserve"
.
.
 "100":"Free"
}
```

I used this query:

```
r.db(DBName).table(tableName).get(docId).values().contains(regex).run(conn);
```

Here: regex is used either **FREE**.

This is giving me all values that are FREE but i was want to get the (keys,Value)-pair for which regex is either Free or Reserved.

Can i retrieve the number of key-value  pair Like,  that are Free by any means?:

```
 "1" :"Free"
 "2" :"Free"
 "100":"Free"
```

insted of getting

```
"Free"
"Free"
"Free"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
r.db("DB").table("TABLENAME").get("DOC_ID").do(function(doc){
  return doc.keys().filter(function(value){
    return doc(value).match("Free")
  }).map(function(key){
    return r.object(key,doc(key))
  })
})
```

Basically you need to filter all the keys where the respective value is "Free". And then return the key and the value